# Trying to change header content type, but it has no effect

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, dompdf

I'm trying to get a pdf generated by dompdf to download, so I wrote  a function that returns dompdf's output, then I changed the headers of the page to include `Content-type: application/pdf`, the only problem is for some reason is the response header is `Content-type: text/html` anyways.  It is a valid pdf file and everything, so I'm kind of at a loss as to why changing the content type isn't working.

```
public function couponDownload($location_uniqid = null) {
    $this->autoRender = $this->layout = false;

    // Set data
    $account = $this->Account->getAccount($this->Auth->user('company_id'));
    $data['Location'] = $account['Location'];

    // Set headers      
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="coupon.pdf"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    // Generate pdf
    echo $this->Location->generateCouponPdf($data); 
}
```

Comment: Did you print out HTML or whitespace before setting the content-type to PDF?  Then it will be stuck as HTML.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's whitespace.  I've had success with just setting headers in CakePHP before by just calling the normal header() function, but apparently using `$this->response->type('pdf');` works in this case while calling header() does not.  Wish I knew why, but at least I have something that works.

Comment: One of you should post an answer so it can be marked as correct, in case anyone else has a similar issue.